# Как создать массив с элементами типа list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, keras

Хочу создать массив NumPy, но чтобы его элементы имели тип `list`.
Как в датасете Reuters из библиотеки Keras.

То есть, чтобы это выглядело так:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[list([1, 2, 2, 8, 43, 10, 447, 5, 25, 207, 270, 5, 3095, 111, 16, 369, 186, 90, 67, 7, 89, 5, 19, 102, 6, 19, 124, 15, 90, 67, 84, 22, 482, 26, 7, 48, 4, 49, 8, 864, 39, 209, 154, 6, 151, 6, 83, 11, 15, 22, 155, 11, 15, 7, 48, 9, 4579, 1005, 504, 6, 258, 6, 272, 11, 15, 22, 134, 44, 11, 15, 16, 8, 197, 1245, 90, 67, 52, 29, 209, 30, 32, 132, 6, 109, 15, 17, 12])
 list([1, 3267, 699, 3434, 2295, 56, 2, 7511, 9, 56, 3906, 1073, 81, 5, 1198, 57, 366, 737, 132, 20, 4093, 7, 2, 49, 2295, 2, 1037, 3267, 699, 3434, 8, 7, 10, 241, 16, 855, 129, 231, 783, 5, 4, 587, 2295, 2, 2, 775, 7, 48, 34, 191, 44, 35, 1795, 505, 17, 12])]
```

Comment: А сами вы пытались что-либо сделать?

Comment: Да, но я не догоняю как засунуть списки внутрь массива, так чтоб их тип сохранился, у меня ток массив массивов получается

Comment: что значит "чтобы их тип сохранился"? Приведите пример входных и выходных данных и ваши попытки решения...

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос - вы можете воспользоваться [keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequence()](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/).

Пример:

```
In [104]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8]])

In [105]: a
Out[105]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])], dtype=object)

In [106]: from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

In [107]: pad_sequences(a, maxlen=3)
Out[107]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [108]: pad_sequences(a, maxlen=3, truncating='post')
Out[108]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [109]: pad_sequences(a, maxlen=4)
Out[109]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [110]: pad_sequences(a, maxlen=4, padding='post', truncating='post')
Out[110]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```